# Fire trigger on DISABLE TRIGGER

Tags: sql-server, triggers, ddl-trigger

There's a safety trigger that blocks all SQL DDL events (ALTER/DROP/CREATE etc.) on a production database instance.

For deployments you'd do `DISABLE TRIGGER` and then `ENABLE TRIGGER` when done.

I'd like an Operator to be notified (`EXEC sp_notify_operator ...`) when the safety trigger is DISABLED/ENABLED. They don't appear to be [DDL events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510452.aspx) and I can't add an UPDATE/DELETE trigger on `sys.triggers` either. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Since you're already "protected" so to speak from DDL statements being executed, you could add another database trigger looking for DDL events that calls a procedure to notify an operator.  You might need another layer of management though - maybe something to queue the notifications - so that it doesn't become too spammy. I could envision changes being rolled out and receiving 100+ email notices...yuck.

```
CREATE TRIGGER DatabaseDDLNotices
ON DATABASE FOR DDL_DATABASE_LEVEL_EVENTS
AS BEGIN
  -- place something into a queue to be batched later
END;
```

In my opinion this also has the nice side effect of keeping notification logic and DDL prevention logic separated.

Comment: Yeah that's an interesting idea. I guess the fact that you can't put a trigger on `{EN,DIS}ABLE TRIGGER` must be by design - otherwise you could get the SQL server into a pretty nasty state which you can't leave because triggers blow up everything you do including attempts to fix the triggers.

Comment: There is a problem with this solution in 2008 http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/509242/fire-a-ddl-trigger-when-the-new-syntax-disable-trigger-is-executed